# Query to return 2 random and one specific result

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write a query which can return 3 results, in a random order. One of the results must always be a specific row in the table

For example out of:

- Apple
- Orange
- Banana
- Melon

I want to always return Melon and also return 2 of the other records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `order by`.  The following will always put `Melon` first:

```
order by (fruit = 'Melon') desc,
         rand()
limit 3;
```

Comment: But that's not what is required! :-(

Comment: Yes, it is. +1 Why don't you think so, Strawberry?

Comment: @fancyPants Maybe because it might not work if there are more than two occurences of `melon`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 . . . That is true.  But the sample data and question do not suggest that this is an issue.  The sample data explicitly has one row with `Melon`.